# Arithmetic complexity of mod powers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, computational-complexity

Given $a,b,p\in\Bbb N$ what is the computational complexity of computing $a^{p^b}\bmod p$? Is it $O((\log a)(\log b)(\log p))$ arithmetic operations on $\log p$ sized words?

$p$ need not be prime.

Comment: Is $p$ definitely prime?

Comment: @Element118 would it matter?

Comment: You can use the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) that $a^{\phi(p)}\equiv1\pmod p$